# TS 2349: Why is a cast necessary despite control flow based type guard?

Tags: casting, typescript, typescript1.8

In Typescript 1.8.9

Given

```
  type templateUrlFunction = (locale?:string) => string;
  type templateUrlParameter = string | templateUrlFunction;

  private _templateUrl:templateUrlParameter;
```

Why do I have to cast _templateUrl even though I am doing type guarding using control flow like:

```
let templateUrl:string;
if (typeof this._templateUrl === 'function') {
  templateUrl = (<templateUrlFunction>this._templateUrl)($translate.use());
} else if (typeof this._templateUrl === 'string') {
  templateUrl = <string>this._templateUrl;
}
```

The examples that I have seen for type guarding do not require casting.  If I do not cast, I get the error:
`2349 Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.` on the line where cast to `<templateUrlFunction>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because type guarding doesn't work on properties in TS < 2.0.

One possible workaround is to put it in a variable first:

```
let templateUrlProperty = this._templateUrl;
let templateUrl: string;

if (typeof templateUrlProperty === 'function') {
  templateUrl = templateUrlProperty($translate.use());
} else if (typeof templateUrlProperty === 'string') {
  templateUrl = templateUrlProperty;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault.  I was trying to adapt a larger bit of code to a short example.  _templateUrl is actually a member.   I've updated the code example in the question.